How to plot a stacked barchart in phyloseq of relative abundances per sampling site with different sampling sizes?
I have a really basic phyloseq question which I annoyingly am unable to resolve.
I have a phyloseq object (OTU table, taxonomy, and sample data) with 4 sample variables like this

Sample Data:        [16 samples by 4 sample variables]

             type Plot  host_species block



I have done a transformation of sample counts, agglomeration and a psmelt:
#Genus1pct root
ps.rel3 = transform_sample_counts(ps.root, function(x) x/sum(x)*100)
# agglomerate taxa
glom3 <- tax_glom(ps.rel3, taxrank = 'Genus1pct', NArm = FALSE)
ps.melt3 <- psmelt(glom3)

in order to do a stacked barchart of my 16 samples here, divided by the three host species (Dryas, Salix, and Kobresia):
#level_order <- factor(species, c(')))
ggplot(ps.melt3, aes(x = Sample, y = Abundance, fill = Genus1pct)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", aes(fill=Genus1pct)) + 
  labs(x="", y="%",title = "Roots") +
  facet_wrap(~sample_species, scales= "free_x", nrow=1) +
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(legend.position = "right", 
        strip.background = element_blank(), 
        axis.text.x.bottom = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x.bottom = element_blank())


However, I would like to do a stacked barchart with relative abundances by my three host species now.
How do I do this? I am basically looking for something like a transform_sample_counts-function just for sample variables. (This must, of course, be able to account
This is a (hapless) ggplot just plotting the host_species as x, without having done the transformation:

There are 5,6 and 5 samples on each of the three host species, and obviously I would like this plot here with even heights summing to a 100%.

Can you provide dput(ps.melt3)? Perhaps you just want that last plot, but using geom_col(position = 'fill')?

Substituting geom_bar(stat = "identity", aes(fill=Genus1pct))
with
geom_col(position=fill)
does appear to give me the desired output. I am not quite sure I understand the dput question, it  just gives me the +1000 rows of information of psmelt3 that are far too much to provide here. Let me know if I am missing something.

That should be + geom_col(aes(fill = Genus1pct), position = "fill") (which is the same as + geom_bar(aes(fill = Genus1pct), stat = "identity", position = "fill"). I was asking for the dput so that we can actually run your code instead of just guessing at solutions. If you have too much data, give the dput of a sample of your data, and edit your question to include it.
